# IQueryable and ISession

Tags: linq, iqueryable, isession

Which way is better to use?

```
ISession session = SessionController.Factory.OpenSession();
IQueryable<myObject> myObjectdquery;
```

1.

```
myObjectquery = session.Query<myObject>();  
myObjectquery = myObjectquery.Where(x=>x....)
```

or

2.

```
myObjectquery = session.Query<myObject>().Where(x=>x...);
```

I'm not sure is my logic correct but in first approach myObjectquery is first "filled" with data and then queried, and in second approach one step is skipped and myObjectquery is filled only with necessary data. The point is what is faster?

Comment: There is no difference. In both cases you call `Query` on `session` and `Where` on the result of that call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.
>
> myObjectquery = session.Query();
>   myObjectquery =
>   myObjectquery.Where(x=>x....) or
>
> 2.
>
> myObjectquery = session.Query().Where(x=>x...);

They are exactly the same thing, just look at it. If you already know that and want to chose which one to go with, go with number 2, it's easier to ready and you have fewer code lines.

P.S: Your query is 'filled' with data in 1st example, but not in memory, so it doesn't matter. So yeah, it's the same thing.

Comment: "Your query is 'filled' with data in 1st example, but not in memory" What does this mean? The variable just references a _query_, no data, in memory or otherwise.

Comment: Yes, i agree with you. Here is what he wrote: "I'm not sure is my logic correct but in first approach myObjectquery is first "filled" with data and then queried". I was simply telling him that it makes no difference, cause no data is actually loaded at all.